# How to give radio button functions in a alert dialog?

Tags: android

So I have made a alert dialog box with 3 options. So, if the first option is selected and something specific is entered into a edit text field it changes a text view into something specific. How do I go about giving the radio button a function?

Comment: Please explain and show what have you tried ?

Comment: you need to create custom alert dialog which is contain radio buttons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
radioGroup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int checkedRadioButton = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                switch (checkedRadioButton) {
                case R.id.firstRadioBtn: //id of first radio button
                    //code goes here if first radio button is clicked
                    break;
                case R.id.secondRadioBtn://id of second radio button
                    //code goes here if second radio button is clicked
                    break;
                case R.id.thirdRadioBtn://id of third radio button
                    //code goes here if third radio button is clicked
                    break;

                }
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want....

```
 RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
// your code here
            }
        });
```

here inside the code block you will do something specific or whatever....  ;)

you must use

`RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);`
 if this is a part of your dialog....

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you can get it in a much easier way like this

```
 builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, checkeditem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```